# What do chemical constituent measurement units 'g%g' and 'µg g⁻¹' mean?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I'm trying to understand the following data being presented in [this](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01904169709365252?journalCode=lpla20#preview) paper measuring the mineral content of the *Cannabis sativa* plant (leaves and inflorescences):

[image]

I need to interpret these data readings in terms of simple percentages.

What would the first two examples - sodium and potassium - translate to in simple percentage / ppm etc.?

Comment: I am not sure if Mathematics would be a better site for this question, (the theme/context is chemistry though the question itself specifically on mathematical units of data measurement), suggestions welcome about that!

Comment: I'm not sure I've seen the g%g, but micrograms/gram is interpreted as micrograms of the element per gram of the sample, so in parts per million.  I would lean toward g%g being a percentage, so parts per hundred.

Answer (score 5):

$\pu{g\%g}$ literally means grams per cent grams or grams of mineral per $\pu{100g}$ of sample. So, in population 1 there is $\pu{2.33g}$ of $\ce{K}$ per $\pu{100g}$ of leaves. Not bad when you consider cooked spinach only has about$\pu{0.05\%}$ $\ce{K}$! Eat your greens, kids. About $\pu{2\%}$ $\ce{K}$ in plants is average across a broad spectrum of plants.

$\pu{ug g-1}$ is micrograms of mineral per gram of sample. Population 1 has 23 micrograms of $\ce{Na}$ per gram of leaves.

You should be able to convert these to percents or ppm, as needed, and check in the text as to whether this refers to dry weight of plant or not. I'm guessing with this multivariate array of mineral analyses, the origin of particular cannabis crops could be determined.